# Conditional Style can't change backcolor

Tags: java, jasper-reports, report

I'm using Jasper Report 
Basically, my problem is i can't change backcolor when it's the field is null using conditional styles in Styles tag

I don't know the problem form the condition statement or the conditional style can't change when the condition is true.

so, i hope to find solution for this problem, In the following below i my Report file code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports"    
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"      
xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports    
http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="FEP_ENERGY_DATA" 
language="groovy" pageWidth="1333" pageHeight="1350" whenNoDataType="NoDataSection" 
columnWidth="1293" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20">
<property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
<property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
<property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.style.evaluation.time.enabled" value="true"/>

<style name="style_TOU">
    <conditionalStyle>
        <conditionExpression><![CDATA[$F{TOTAL_EXP} == null]]></conditionExpression>
        <style mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFFF00"/>
    </conditionalStyle>
    <conditionalStyle>
        <conditionExpression><![CDATA[$F{TOU1_KWH_EXP} == null]]></conditionExpression>
        <style mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFFF00"/>
    </conditionalStyle>
    <conditionalStyle>
        <conditionExpression><![CDATA[$F{TOU2_KWH_EXP} == null]]></conditionExpression>
        <style mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFCC00"/>
    </conditionalStyle>
    <conditionalStyle>
        <conditionExpression><![CDATA[$F{TOU3_KWH_EXP} == null]]></conditionExpression>
        <style mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FF3300"/>
    </conditionalStyle>
    <conditionalStyle>
        <conditionExpression><![CDATA[$F{TOU4_KWH_EXP} == null]]></conditionExpression>
        <style mode="Opaque" backcolor="#77BCD4"/>
    </conditionalStyle>
</style>


<parameter name="daydate" class="java.lang.String"/>
<parameter name="metersId" class="java.util.Collection"/>
<parameter name="imagepath" class="java.lang.String"/>
<queryString>
    <![CDATA[WITH METER_ENERGY_DATA AS
      (
                 SELECT MTR_INFO.MTR_ID, MTR_INFO.MTR_SLNO AS METER_SLNO ,MTR_INFO.ACCOUNT_NO AS ACCOUNT_NO, MTR_INFO.SUB_NO AS SUB_NO,
                        CONVERT(varchar,ENERGY_TOU.TOTAL_EXP) as TOTAL_EXP, CONVERT(varchar,ENERGY_TOU.TOU1_EXP) as TOU1_KWH_EXP,
                        CONVERT(varchar,ENERGY_TOU.TOU2_EXP) as TOU2_KWH_EXP, CONVERT(varchar,ENERGY_TOU.TOU3_EXP) as TOU3_KWH_EXP,
                        CONVERT(varchar,ENERGY_TOU.TOU4_EXP) as TOU4_KWH_EXP , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY 
                        ENERGY_TOU.METER_ID ORDER BY ENERGY_TOU.METER_TIME DESC) ROW_NUM
                 FROM   AECMDMS_DEV.dbo.METER_INFO AS MTR_INFO
                 LEFT JOIN
                 (SELECT * FROM AECMDMS_DEV.dbo.ENERGY_WITH_TOU as ENERGY
                  WHERE ENERGY.METER_TIME BETWEEN '2014-01-10' AND '2014-01-10 23:59:59.999' ) AS ENERGY_TOU ON (ENERGY_TOU.METER_ID = MTR_INFO.MTR_ID)
                 )

                  SELECT METER_SLNO ,ACCOUNT_NO, SUB_NO,  LEFT(TOTAL_EXP,LEN(TOTAL_EXP)-2) as TOTAL_EXP, LEFT(TOU1_KWH_EXP, LEN(TOU1_KWH_EXP)-2) AS TOU1_KWH_EXP ,LEFT(TOU2_KWH_EXP, LEN(TOU2_KWH_EXP)-2) AS TOU2_KWH_EXP, LEFT(TOU3_KWH_EXP, LEN(TOU3_KWH_EXP)-2) AS TOU3_KWH_EXP, LEFT(TOU4_KWH_EXP, LEN(TOU4_KWH_EXP)-2) AS TOU4_KWH_EXP
                  FROM METER_ENERGY_DATA AS MTR_ENERGY
                  WHERE MTR_ENERGY.ROW_NUM = 1
     ]]>
</queryString>
<field name="METER_SLNO" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="ACCOUNT_NO" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="SUB_NO" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="TOTAL_EXP" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="TOU1_KWH_EXP" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="TOU2_KWH_EXP" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="TOU3_KWH_EXP" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="TOU4_KWH_EXP" class="java.lang.String"/>
<background>
    <band splitType="Stretch"/>
</background>
<title>
    <band height="102" splitType="Stretch">
        <image scaleImage="FillFrame">
            <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" x="421" y="0" width="370" height="70"/>
            <imageExpression><![CDATA[$P{imagepath}]]></imageExpression>
        </image>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="2" y="81" width="1292" height="20"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                <font size="12" isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["ENERGY DATA EXPORT ON "+$P{daydate}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
    </band>
</title>
<pageHeader>
    <band height="31" splitType="Stretch">
        <frame>
            <reportElement x="0" y="20" width="1292" height="10"/>
        </frame>
    </band>
</pageHeader>
<columnHeader>
    <band height="40" splitType="Stretch">
        <frame>
            <reportElement x="2" y="0" width="1294" height="40"/>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement mode="Opaque"   x="564" y="20" width="110" height="20" forecolor="#000000" backcolor="#77BCD4"/>
                <box rightPadding="5">
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.75" lineColor="#CCCCCC"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="10" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[TOTAL]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement mode="Opaque" style="style_TOU" x="674" y="20" width="110" height="20" forecolor="#000000" backcolor="#77BCD4"/>
                <box rightPadding="5">
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.75" lineColor="#CCCCCC"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="10" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[TOU 1]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="784" y="20" width="110" height="20" forecolor="#000000" backcolor="#77BCD4"/>
                <box rightPadding="5">
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.75" lineColor="#CCCCCC"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="10" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[TOU 2]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="894" y="20" width="110" height="20" forecolor="#000000" backcolor="#77BCD4"/>
                <box rightPadding="5">
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.75" lineColor="#CCCCCC"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="10" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[TOU 3]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="1004" y="20" width="110" height="20" forecolor="#000000" backcolor="#77BCD4"/>
                <box rightPadding="5">
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.75" lineColor="#CCCCCC"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="10" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[TOU 4]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="564" y="0" width="550" height="20" forecolor="#000000" backcolor="#77BCD4"/>
                <box>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.75" lineColor="#CCCCCC"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#CCCCCC"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#CCCCCC"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="10" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Active Energy(kWh)]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="178" y="0" width="130" height="40" forecolor="#000000" backcolor="#77BCD4"/>
                <box leftPadding="5">
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.75" lineColor="#CCCCCC"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="10" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Serial No.]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="436" y="0" width="128" height="40" forecolor="#000000" backcolor="#77BCD4"/>
                <box rightPadding="5">
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.75" lineColor="#CCCCCC"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="10" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Subscribtion No.]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </frame>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="310" y="0" width="128" height="40" forecolor="#000000" backcolor="#77BCD4"/>
            <box rightPadding="5">
                <leftPen lineWidth="0.75" lineColor="#CCCCCC"/>
            </box>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font fontName="Arial" size="10" isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[Account No.]]></text>
        </staticText>
    </band>
</columnHeader>
<detail>
    <band height="24" splitType="Stretch">
        <rectangle>
            <reportElement x="180" y="0" width="936" height="24" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" backcolor="#D0E8F0">
                <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$V{REPORT_COUNT}.intValue() % 2 != 1]]></printWhenExpression>
            </reportElement>
            <graphicElement>
                <pen lineWidth="0.0" lineColor="#CCCCCC"/>
            </graphicElement>
        </rectangle>
        <frame>
            <reportElement x="180" y="0" width="936" height="24" backcolor="#FFFFFF"/>
            <textField pattern="###0.0">
                <reportElement mode="Transparent" x="258" y="0" width="128" height="24" backcolor="#CCCCCC"/>
                <box rightPadding="3">
                    <pen lineWidth="0.75" lineColor="#CCCCCC"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.75" lineColor="#CCCCCC"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.75" lineColor="#CCCCCC"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.75" lineColor="#CCCCCC"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.75" lineColor="#CCCCCC"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{SUB_NO}+" "]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField evaluationTime="Band">
                <reportElement mode="Transparent" style="style_TOU" x="386"  y="0" width="110" height="24"/>
                <box rightPadding="3">
                    <pen lineWidth="0.75" lineColor="#CCCCCC"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.75" lineColor="#CCCCCC"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.75" lineColor="#CCCCCC"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.75" lineColor="#CCCCCC"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.75" lineColor="#CCCCCC"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{TOTAL_EXP} ==  null ? "n/a" : $F{TOTAL_EXP} +" "]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField evaluationTime="Band">
                <reportElement mode="Transparent" style="style_TOU" x="496" y="0" width="110" height="24"/>
                <box rightPadding="3">
                    <pen lineWidth="0.75" lineColor="#CCCCCC"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.75" lineColor="#CCCCCC"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.75" lineColor="#CCCCCC"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.75" lineColor="#CCCCCC"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.75" lineColor="#CCCCCC"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{TOU1_KWH_EXP}== null ? "n/a" : $F{TOU1_KWH_EXP} +" "]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField evaluationTime="Band">
                <reportElement mode="Transparent" style="style_TOU" x="606" y="0" width="110" height="24"/>
                <box rightPadding="3">
                    <pen lineWidth="0.75" lineColor="#CCCCCC"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.75" lineColor="#CCCCCC"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.75" lineColor="#CCCCCC"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.75" lineColor="#CCCCCC"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.75" lineColor="#CCCCCC"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{TOU2_KWH_EXP} == null ? "n/a" : $F{TOU2_KWH_EXP}+" "]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField evaluationTime="Band">
                <reportElement mode="Transparent" style="style_TOU" x="716" y="0" width="110" height="24"/>
                <box rightPadding="3">
                    <pen lineWidth="0.75" lineColor="#CCCCCC"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.75" lineColor="#CCCCCC"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.75" lineColor="#CCCCCC"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.75" lineColor="#CCCCCC"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.75" lineColor="#CCCCCC"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{TOU3_KWH_EXP} == null ? "n/a" : $F{TOU3_KWH_EXP} +" "]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField evaluationTime="Band">
                <reportElement mode="Transparent" style="style_TOU" x="826" y="0" width="110" height="24"/>
                <box rightPadding="3">
                    <pen lineWidth="0.75" lineColor="#CCCCCC"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.75" lineColor="#CCCCCC"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.75" lineColor="#CCCCCC"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.75" lineColor="#CCCCCC"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.75" lineColor="#CCCCCC"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{TOU4_KWH_EXP} == null ? "n/a" : $F{TOU4_KWH_EXP} +" "]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField pattern="###0.0">
                <reportElement mode="Transparent" x="130" y="0" width="126" height="24" backcolor="#CCCCCC"/>
                <box rightPadding="3">
                    <pen lineWidth="0.75" lineColor="#CCCCCC"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.75" lineColor="#CCCCCC"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.75" lineColor="#CCCCCC"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.75" lineColor="#CCCCCC"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.75" lineColor="#CCCCCC"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{ACCOUNT_NO}+" "]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement mode="Transparent" x="0" y="0" width="130" height="24" backcolor="#CCCCCC"/>
                <box leftPadding="5">
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#CCCCCC"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.75" lineColor="#CCCCCC"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#CCCCCC"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#CCCCCC"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{METER_SLNO}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </frame>
    </band>
</detail>
<pageFooter>
    <band height="20" splitType="Stretch">
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="994" y="0" width="80" height="20"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Page "+$V{PAGE_NUMBER}+" of"]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField evaluationTime="Report">
            <reportElement x="1074" y="0" width="42" height="20"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[" " + $V{PAGE_NUMBER}+" "]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField pattern="dd/MM/yyyy h.mm a">
            <reportElement x="182" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[new java.util.Date()]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
    </band>
</pageFooter>
<noData>
    <band height="33" splitType="Stretch">
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="522" y="0" width="291" height="31"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font size="24" isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[No Data To Display]]></text>
        </staticText>
    </band>
</noData>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have `mode=Transparent` on field level and that has higher priority then `mode=Opaque` at style level. Set the `Transparent` on style and remove it from fields, currently your conditional style sets background color on transparent fields.
Change text field from:

```
       <textField pattern="###0.0">
            <reportElement mode="Transparent" ...
```

to (1):

```
       <textField pattern="###0.0">
            <reportElement ...
```

or (2):

```
       <textField pattern="###0.0">
            <reportElement mode="Opaque" ...
```

I'm not sure which of those you can set but it should work after you change that.
Also if you want the field to be transparent when condition is not satisfied you could change style to this:

```
 <style name="style_TOU" mode="Transparent">
```

The way you wrote your style you will change background on all the fields if any of them is null. I think you will have to write separate style for each field if you want to change the color only for the field with null value....

Comment: still not changing, if you can PLEASE explain by writing xml code!